# Excel Get Data links breaking

Tags: excel, powerquery

I made an excel workbook the pulls data from a comma separated value formatted .txt document.

The document is supposed to be updated automatically every month. This happens with a power automate script that scans my email and then saves the attachment into a SharePoint drive.

The document maintains the same name and format every month.

However, I am having an issue with the source link in excel getting broken after the document has been replaced.

Anyone know of a way to diagnose/repair this issue?

I am currently updating the link manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is lacking debugging details. You didn't mention the data connector you are using. Make sure it's **From SharePoint List** and not the local copy of your SharePoint data.

Comment: Thank you Peter. That is what the problem was.